# input textbox values not saving to database when one or more fields are empty

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using angular with entity framework to save data to a SQL back-end database.

When i complete all fields in the web form, it saves to the database.  If i leave one field blank (which isn't required) then none of the items save to the database.  The database columns are all nullable.

Here is the JS:

```
        $scope.saveData = function () {
        $http.post("/AddTeam/SaveData", {
            recordID: $scope.formGuid,
            GenAddress1: $scope.formData.GenAddress1,
            GenAddress2: $scope.formData.GenAddress2,
            GenAddress3: $scope.formData.GenAddress3,
            GenCity: $scope.formData.GenCity,
            GenPostCode: $scope.formData.GenPostCode,
            GenPhoneNo: $scope.formData.GenPhoneNo,
            GenFaxNo: $scope.formData.GenFaxNo,
            TodaysDate: $scope.TodaysDate,
            GenDeactivationDate: $scope.formData.GenDeactivationDate
        })
            .success(function (result) {
                $scope.teams = result;
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    }
```

Here is the Controller in C#

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveData(string recordID, string GenAddress1, string GenAddress2, string GenAddress3, string GenCity,
        string GenPostCode, string GenPhoneNo, string GenFaxNo, DateTime TodaysDate, DateTime GenDeactivationDate)
    {
        var db = new MYDBEntities();
        db.WebForms_MyTable.Add(new WebForms_MyTable()
        {
           RecordID = recordID,
           AddressLine1 = GenAddress1,
           AddressLine2 = GenAddress2,
           AddressLine3 = GenAddress3,
           City = GenCity,
           Postcode = GenPostCode,
           PhoneNumber = GenPhoneNo,
           FaxNumber = GenFaxNo,
           ActivationDate = TodaysDate,
           DeactivationDate = GenDeactivationDate
        });
```

Do you know why this could be?

Thank

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in your C# code?

Comment: Try printing the values in JS before post call. See if they are printed correctly. And are you sure a post call is even made when you leave one of the fields empty?

Comment: Just added a breakpoint in my c# - and funny when i complete all fields it hits the c#.  When i leave a field empty it doesnt hit the c#... so perhaps I'm missing something in my JS....

Comment: Okay I've relalised what it is - when a DateTime field is left empty the JS doesn't pass it to the c# controller.... when a text field is left empty it does.... hmmmm....

Answer (score 0):

Okay i fixed it by changing the declaration of the DateTime fields from 'DateTime' to 'DateTime?'

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveData(string recordID, string GenAddress1, string GenAddress2, string GenAddress3, string GenCity,
    string GenPostCode, string GenPhoneNo, string GenFaxNo, DateTime? TodaysDate, DateTime? GenDeactivationDate)
{
    var db = new MYDBEntities();
    db.WebForms_MyTable.Add(new WebForms_MyTable()
    {
       RecordID = recordID,
       AddressLine1 = GenAddress1,
       AddressLine2 = GenAddress2,
       AddressLine3 = GenAddress3,
       City = GenCity,
       Postcode = GenPostCode,
       PhoneNumber = GenPhoneNo,
       FaxNumber = GenFaxNo,
       ActivationDate = TodaysDate,
       DeactivationDate = GenDeactivationDate
    });
```